# Defining specific attr_accessor methods in order to distinguish several types of instance variables

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

When describing classes, I would like to be able to diffentiate different kind of instance variables, using a dedicated class methods (let's call it my_attrs_1, my_attrs_2). Something like :

```
class DesignUnit
  attrs_1 :a,:b
  attrs_2 :c  
end
```

So that I can iterate through these different instance variables like this :

```
du=DesignUnit.new
#...
du.attrs_1.each do ...
   #I get a, and b
end
```

My starting point is to have a look at how to customize attr_acessor definition (for instance [here](http://maxivak.com/ruby-metaprogramming-and-own-attr_accessor/)), but I didn't succeed to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
module CustomAttributeCollector
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end
  module ClassMethods
    def attrs_1(*args)
      @_attrs_1 ||= []
      (args - @_attrs_1).each do |arg|
        attr_accessor arg
        @_attrs_1 << arg
      end
    end
    def attrs_2(*args)
      @_attrs_2 ||= []
      (args - @_attrs_2).each do |arg|
        attr_accessor arg
        @_attrs_2 << arg
      end    
    end
  end
  def attrs_1 
    self.class.instance_variable_get("@_attrs_1")
  end
  def attrs_2
    self.class.instance_variable_get("@_attrs_2")
  end 
end     

class DesignUnit
 include CustomAttributeCollector
  attrs_1 :a,:b
  attrs_2 :c
end
```

then

```
du = DesignUnit.new
du.attrs_1
#=> [:a,:b]
du.attrs_2
#=> [:c]
du.methods.sort - Object.methods
#=> [:a, :a=, :attrs_1, :attrs_2, :b, :b=, :c, :c=]
```

Obviously this could clearly use some clean up and refactoring but I think as an example it accomplishes your goal.